# Embedding URL in html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a function which embeds the following in an HTML document

```
var link = "http://example.org"
$('.class').append('<a href="#" onclick="myFunction("'+link+'")">
```

This results in

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(" http: example.org")"
```

How can I escape the forward slashes when embedding them as an onclick function argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not that you need to escape the slashes in the variable, but you instead have mis-matched quotes in the HTML you're building. Try this:

```
var link = "http://example.org";
$('.class').append('<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(\'' + link + '\')">Foo</a>');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xw8du5kb/)

Comment: Thanks very much this worked. I knew it'd be something simple I had overlooked ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var link = "http:\/\/example.org";
$('.class').append('<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(\''+link+'\')">
```

Comment: Turns out I had the HTML syntax wrong so just replacing " with \' has fixed it.